# Unable to operate simple mathematical operation using user form with excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a user form do doing some mathematical operation like multiply and divide. Where I want to divide input value (obtained through user form) into halves. But I made a mistake don't know where because as soon as I clicked on radio button (rdio_cgst) vba shws an compile error with error 'Object required'. Please help me to find out the mistake.
Help is highly appreciable.

```
Private Sub RDIO_CGST_Click()

    If LIST_GST <> "" And RDIO_CGST.Value = True Then
        Sheets("BILLING").Range("W19").Value = LIST_GST
        Sheets("BILLING").Range("I19").Value = LIST_GST/ 2
        Sheets("BILLING").Range("J19").Value = LIST_GST/ 2
        Sheets("BILLING").Range("K19").Value = 0
   Else
        Sheets("BILLING").Range("I19").Value = 0
        Sheets("BILLING").Range("J19").Value = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming `LIST_GST` is a range like `RDIO_CGST` is, try replacing `LIST_GST` with `LIST_GST.Value` every time that you reference it

Comment: ....or if `LIST_GST` is a *named range*, use `RANGE("LIST_GST").Value`

Comment: RDIO_CGST.Value is perhaps the issue (typo), as you use the same name as the button name.

Comment: I have tried these suggestions (.value) already.